# apricot Release' does no longer have a Release file

Tags: apt, deepin

I am currently using Deepin 15.11 and I'm trying to perform the `sudo apt-get update` command. I keep getting the error which says that the apricot Release no longer has a release file.

I was having the same problem before with the lion Release but fixed it by changing it to apricot and it actually worked as I was able to perform an update and also install the git software which I couldn't before. It seems now that the problem is back again.

I hope somebody can help coz I've tried so many things already [image]

Comment: maybe the problem is same as last time

Comment: `I've tried so many things` does not mean anything specific .... what did you try?

Comment: I tried running this command: $ sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

Comment: @jsotola, Should I list every command I tried running?

Comment: "maybe the problem is same as last time." So what might I do to solve it this time?

Comment: do the same thing that you did the last time

Comment: As a general comment, please dont't post [screenshots of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read and inaccessible to search engines and people with visual impairments that rely on reading aids. Instead, copy-and-paste the text into the question using block code formatting.